# AD Schema Refresh

Tags: 2010

I am trying to pull newly added custom AD attributes into SharePoint.

I followed this link to refresh the Forefront Identity schema through management agent.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/zaquinn/archive/2012/03/02/custom-ad-schema-attribute-synchronizing-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx

However, I get the attached error when refreshing the schema.

How can I get past this error?

Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might fall under KB940007. Take a look and see if this applies to your case.

"A valid entry in the proxyAddresses attribute becomes an eliminated attribute value in the metaverse schema, or the group membership is truncated in the Active Directory Application Mode management agent in Identity Integration Feature Pack"

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940007

Comment: Found a related technet article with a link to both of the pages we have referenced.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/05209e6c-d146-42a3-8a29-8c04ddae1c52/not-able-to-synchronize-ad-with-user-profie